# Turning on and off LEDs based on button input in ARM assembly

Tags: embedded, arm, assembly, msp432

I am using an [MSP432P401R](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas826e/slas826e.pdf). Attempting to turn on an LED when the button is pressed, and turn on a different one when the button is not pressed. It compiles but doesn’t do anything or light up either of the LEDs at all. I can't tell if I've made a fatal mistake or if I am missing something minor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        area Lab4, code, readonly
        export __main

__main proc

        ;config gpio
        ldr r0, = 0x40004C00    ;port 1 base address
        add r0, #0x40           ;port 5 base address

        ; add code to configure p5dir, p5ren, and p5out

        mov r1, #0x03           ;set bits 0 and 1 as output(1) and bit 5 as input(0)
        strb r1, [r0, #0x04]    ;move into ddr with offset of 4

        mov r1, #0x10           ;enable resistor for bit 4 using the ren
        strb r1, [r0, #0x06]    ;load to ren with offset of 0x06

        mov r1, #0x00           ;select pull down or pull up using output register
        strb r1, [r0, #0x02]    ; output register has offset of 0x02


repeat

        ldrb r2, [r0, #0x00]    ;load input register value to r2
        and r2, #0x10           ;mask pin 4 (makes sure only bit 5 is high)

        lsr r2, r2, #3          ;shift right 4 so it turns on correct pin

        orr r3, r2, #0x02       ;flip the bit
        lsr r3, r3, #1          ;shift right
        orr r3, r3, r2          ;"add" the two together
        strb r3, [r0, #0x02]    ;

        b repeat

        endp
        end
```

Comment: Why do you not know if there is a fatal mistake or a minor mistake? Does it work? Does it compile? It is unclear what help you need or what you are asking. Can you edit in an answerable question?